# Error in importing NiftyNet with Tensorflow 1.9

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, niftynet

I installed the package [`NiftyNet 0.3.0`](http://niftynet.io/) with `Python 2.7.5` on [`CentOS`](https://www.centos.org/) Linux 7.5. `Tensorflow 1.9` was installed a priori. When I import `NiftyNet`, I got the following error message.

```
$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)] on linux2

>> import niftynet

INFO:tensorflow:TensorFlow version 1.9.0

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/niftynet/__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
  set_logger()
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/niftynet/io/misc_io.py", line 633, in set_logger
  tf.logging._logger.handlers = []
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_logger'
```

A similar problem was reported as [an issue of its GitHub repository](https://github.com/NifTK/NiftyNet/issues/96), which states that `NiftyNet` might not be supported by the recent versions of `Tensorflow` (>=1.8).

Unfortunately, it is not allowed to downgrade `Tensorflow` to the version 1.7 in the Linux server as a non-administrator. Could anyone suggest any tip to solve this incompatibility of `NiftyNet` with `Tensorflow 1.9`? If possible, I am willing to revise its source codes which were released in [GitHub repository](https://github.com/NifTK/NiftyNet). Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The latest dev branch supports TF 1.9, you can follow these steps to install: https://github.com/NifTK/NiftyNet/wiki/NiftyNet-FAQ